# Tmux middle click paste buffer is only working on one pane

Tags: tmux, mouse

I use tmux 1.8 with putty. I often copy stuff to the tmux paste buffer using mouse select and then paste using middle click. However, on a new computer, the following issue is happening: when I click the middle mouse button on different panes, it only works on one of them and fails to paste in the rest. The oddest thing is that the one pane I can paste in is the first pane in that window and I can't paste in any of the others, regardless of which pane I copied from.

Answer (score 0):

How wide is your terminal? Standard mouse mode only supports a limited number of columns and 1.8 may be too old for SGR mode.

Comment: How can I find out the width of the terminal?

Comment: echo $COLUMNS aa

Comment: My old setup which was working without issues had 346 columns on a maximized tmux while my new one has 318 columns. I normally work with an equal vertical split

Comment: Are you running tmux in the same terminal and the same terminal version?

Comment: I moved from kitty to putty but everything else should be the same

Comment: 346 columns needs SGR or UTF-8 mouse mode to work. 1.8 should support both, although I don't know if putty supports either (I am guessing not)

Comment: I can reproduce the bug with any terminal size and either vertical or horizontal split: mouse-paste works in first pane, but not in the second pane. keyboard-paste works in both, but is bound to a silly combination ctrl+b,release,attgr+] (I always keep the default config because I work on too many machines, sometimes even with shared user accounts).
I also notice that mouse-paste puts tmux in a state where it waits for more keyboard commands, so I have to press q to exit that mode.
Tested with terminal mintty 3.4.4